# Get Html from a Url in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I need to save a page from url - This page is in my own application - in html format. This html will then be send by email to a user. Any anyone knows how?

Comment: Are you expecting to collect referenced resources such as IMGs and CSS as well?

Comment: Yes I need everything. The user has to open the Html and see the page like he will see it in internet.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, you'll have to do it at the server to be able to e-mail - so at worst, simply:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    string html = client.DownloadString(address);
}
```

It might also be possible to do it *directly* within MVC - perhaps `RenderPartial`?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Result Filter or override the OnResultExecuted method of the controller to get access to the rendered page.